# Timer inside Mat Dialog in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to send dynamic counter data to the Mat Dialog in Angular Material so the count increments on the Mat Dialog box. However, the data that is sent to the Mat Dialog is static. How does one dynamically update data on a Mat Dialog box ?

Comment: Use `BehaviorSubject` in a shared data service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [**RxJs**](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api) library or just look through this simple [**OVERVIEW**](https://angular.io/guide/observables) from Angular team. Main parts which need your attention are [**Subject**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject) and [**BehaviorSubject**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) (I've choose the last one for your case).

The main idea is to create an observable, which you can subscribe to it many times in different components, and when the value changes, you will get the updated value in all your subscriptions.

Here is rather a simple example, where, I created the **BehaviorSubject** in service, subscribed to it, in two components and updated the value every one second, and as expected, these two components get the updated value: [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrsfk5?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts).

**Here's an Example below:**

**Simple service with observable:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { timeInterval } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  source$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      const newVal = this.source$.getValue() + 1;
      this.source$.next(newVal);
    }, 1000);
  }

  public getObservable() {
    return this.source$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**And here is how you can subscribe on changes:**

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    private _dataService: DataService) {
      _dataService.getObservable().subscribe(val => this.counter = val);
    }
```